# Uncaught TypeError: Dialog.SRTF is not a function at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este error en mi proyecto que no logro resolver.
Es un boton el cual realiza la funcion de compartir mensajes. El error es el siguiente

```
Uncaught TypeError: Dialog.SRTF is not a function
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

La linea de codigo por la que arroja este error es esta

```
{if $MessID == 0 || $MessID == 3 || $MessID == 199 && $Message.oldType == 0 || $MessID == 199 && $Message.oldType == 3}
            <br>
            <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="{$LNG.mg_re}" onclick="return Dialog.SRTF({$Message.id})"><i class="fas fa-share-square"></i></a>
            {/if}
```

Y la funcion es la siguiente:

```
function SRTF(RaportID)
{
    var Name    = $('#upgrade_name').val();
    ally = '';
    if(Name == 'ally')
        ally = 'ally';
    $.post("game.php?page=messages", {'mode': 'SpyRaportToFreind', 'RaportID': RaportID, 'FriendID': Name, 'ally': ally, 'ajax': 1}, function(data)
    {
        $('.ally_contents').text(data);
        setTimeout(function(){ parent.$.fancybox.close();}, 2000);
    }, "json");
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y de donde sale el "Dialog" de `onclick="return Dialog.SRTF({$Message.id})` ?? porque pones eso?

Comment: Ya lo resolví. Me falta agregar la función SRTF a la variable Dialog.